# Slow an object relative to the speed and distance of another object

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I'm having a problem with vehicle movement, acceleration and deceleration and hoping someone can help out.

I have a moving object/vehicle and I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Accelerate to max speed over a period of time
2. Decelerate to a stop when it encounters a stationary object
3. Decelerate to match the speed of a moving object
4. Decelerate as the other object decelerates until both come to a stop

I have got **#1** to **#3** working, but having an issue with **#4**.

I know the speed of the other object and the RaycastHit object gives me the distance, but I'm struggling to get the object to reliably stop in time.

Slowing for stationary objects was easy enough as the distance remains the same, but if the other object is constantly accelerating/decelerating then maintaining a constant distance and coming to a stop is proving a bit more difficult.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to get this working would be appreciated?

Edit #1:

Sorry, forgot to add the code. I cast a ray in front of the object and when it hits something I calculate deceleration with:

```
float deceleration = (_currentSpeed - targetSpeed) / brakeDistance;
```

`_currentSpeed` is the speed of this object. `targetSpeed` is the speed of the other object that I would like to match and `brakeDistance` is the distance between this object and the other object.

`brakeDistance` is calculated as:

```
float gapBetweenObjects = 0.5f;
float brakeDistance = raycastHit.distance - gapBetweenObjects
```

As the other object slows I would like this object to slow as well until both come to a stop while maintaining `gapBetweenObjects`.

Comment: Adding some of your code would be really helpful

Comment: This is unclear. After your first object (**A**) matches velocity with the second object (**B**), you want **A** to maintain a constant distance to **B**, is that right? And you want **A** to do this by calculating its own rate of deceleration as a function of measured distance and desired distance, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create a bool that triggers after the raycast detects an obstacle, then in your `Update` function you should run the code that would decelerate your car.

There's a pretty good explanation on how to decelerate your moving object when it's over a specified threshold using remaining distance:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/631915/accelleration-and-stopping.html

This should be enough to create a base for what you need. Then you would need to determine if detected obstacle is moving and adjust the code according to it.